# Parse: job status message must be a string

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have written a cloud code to change a Boolean value in table. The code is getting executed and the values are getting updated as well. But the issue is that I get the following error printed in my console. I am worried if this might cause a problem if the number of rows increase. Following is the error which is being printed on the console

```
I2015-09-15T06:15:48.317Z]v11: Ran job hello with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: Error: Job status message must be a string
    at updateJobMessageAndReturn (<anonymous>:1157:7)
    at Object.success (<anonymous>:1211:9)
    at e.obj.save.success (main.js:25:30)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:12:27827)
    at e.s (Parse.js:12:26759)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:12:26178)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:12:26831)
    at e.s (Parse.js:12:26759)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:12:26178)
    at e.s (Parse.js:12:26887)
```

Following is the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("hello", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
      var presentDate = new Date();
  // presentDate.setDate(presentDate.getDate()-1);
        presentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var usersValid = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        usersValid.equalTo("emailVerified", true);
        //usersValid.greaterThan("updatedAt", presentDate);
        var users = new Parse.Query("Properties");
        users.matchesQuery("user",usersValid);
        users.equalTo("verified", false);
        users.limit(1000);
        users.find({
        success: function(results) {
             console.log("Total new properties "+ results.length);
             for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var obj = results[i];
                obj.set("verified", true);
                obj.save(null,{
                  success: function (object) { 
                   console.log("Success - "+i);
                    response.success(object);
                  }, 
                error: function (object, error) { 
                 console.log("Failed - "+i);
                  response.error(error);
                }
              });
        }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
response.success(object);
```

you're passing the full object that was just saved - but you shouldn't be. You can just call `success` with a simple status string, like `'OK'`, or with some element from the saved object, like its object id.

The more serious issue is that you're requesting 1000 items in the query and then updating and saving each individually - and in the save completion handler you're calling `success` or `error`. So, as soon as the first of those 1000 objects is saved you're telling the job it's complete and it can stop processing the rest.

You should change your job to use promises instead of old style callbacks and you should put all of the save promises into an array and wait for them to complete after your loop before you call `success` or `error`.